# Stackdump generation on external header function - are the linker options wrong?

Tags: mysql, c, linker

I have a tiny test program using the following code:

```
#include <mysql.h>

int main() {
    printf("Before\n");
    printf("Version: %s\n", mysql_get_client_version());
    printf("After\n");
}
```

And here's what I use to compile: (tasks.json from VS Code)

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-I",
                "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\Connector C++ 8.0\\include",
                "-I",
                "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\include",
                "-L",
                "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\Connector C++ 8.0\\lib64\\vs14",
                "-L",
                "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\lib",
                "${file}",
                "-lmysqlcppconn8",
                "-llibmysql",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\gcc.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've been following the instructions on MySQL's page, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-notes.html

The problem is that whenever the program is run, a stackdump is generated, and I don't understand why. I believe my linker args aren't right, but since nothing else worked to compile, I'm not certain. I have never used external libraries/header files before, (I am completely new to C, but I figured I'd give it a shot to learn something new).

Why would the program fail this way?

Comment: does `mysql_get_client_version` return `char *` or something else?

Comment: I see it returns `unsigned long` [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_get_client_version/) if thats correct use `%lu` instead of `%s` in `printf`

Comment: @IrAM even with %lu it only generates a stack dump. There must be something with the linker options. All that prints is;
"Before
      4 [main] MySQLTest 190 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to MySQLTest.exe.stackdump"